# How can I add margins to a single subfigure so it is all on the same height at its center

Tags: graphics

I just got into Latex and I have to make some graphs etc, I made three graphs with Tikz, that have a different height and tried to get them into my main document with the following code, however all three are sitting at the bottom but I want their centers to be at the same height so it does no look like stairs, is there any way I can add a margin to the bottom of a single subfigure?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Beispiel:}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[a]{\includegraphics\[height=300, width=.40\textwidth\]{example-image-a}}\hfill
    \subfigure[b]{\includegraphics\[height=200, width=.30\textwidth\]{example-image-b}}\hfill
    \subfigure[c]{\includegraphics\[height=100, width=.15\textwidth\]{example-image-c}}\hfill
\caption{BLIPBLUP}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, called MWE (Minimal Working Example), beginning with `\documentclass`, and ending by `\end{document}`. Also explain, where should be captions of subfigures? BTW, `subfigure` package  is obsolete. It is replaced by `subfig`, which define `\subfloat` commands for inserting subfigure. However, in your case probably be better to use `subcaption` package and its environment `subfigure}.

Comment: Hey thank you for your quick anwser, i just added the `\documentclass{article}` the enddocument is alreaedy there. The captions should still be alingend at the bottom, however the pictures should be aligned such that all the centers are on the same height. 

I didnt know about the other things, i am pretty new to Latex and when i looked up how to get multiple figures side by side that was the easiest solution i found. It also worked out just fine for the other Figures which all had the same height. 

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Beispiel:}\bigskip

    \centering\floatsetup{heightadjust=object, valign=c, floatrowsep=qquad}%
    \renewcommand\subfloatrowsep{\hskip 4em}
\ffigbox{\begin{subfloatrow}[3]
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[height=300pt, width=.40\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[height=200pt, width=.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[height=100pt, width=.15\textwidth]{example-image-c}}\hfill
\end{subfloatrow}}{\caption{BLIPBLUP}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much :*

Answer (score 3):

As Zarko mentioned in the comment, you can use the `subfigure` environment from the `subcaption` package. The optional argument `[c]` in the `subfigure` environment aligns all the images in the center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Beispiel:}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=300pt, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=200pt, width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=100pt, width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{BLIPBLUP}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need a caption for each of the sub-figure, you can use the `\caption` command inside the `subfigure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Beispiel:}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=300pt, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption A}\label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=200pt, width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Caption B}\label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=100pt, width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Caption B}\label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{BLIPBLUP}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

Images and their subcaptions are organized in table. For table is used `tabularray` package and for vertical align of images their baselines are moved to their centers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,varwidth}   % <===

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=-1.5ex, belowskip=-2.5ex}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[wd=.40\textwidth] Q[wd=.30\textwidth] Q[wd=.15\textwidth]},
             measure = vbox}        % <===
\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[height=2cm, width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-b}
        &   \includegraphics[height=1cm, width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-c}    \\
\subcaption{} & \subcaption{}   &  \subcaption{}
\end{tblr}
\caption{BLIPBLUP}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes exactly thank you very much!

Comment: @JakobKilianNukenja, if you like my answer, you can consider upvote it :-)

Comment: I could now! Thank you. Bevor that it said something that i needed to fulfill some requiremnts to upvote. Thank you again!